# Get amount of function arguments OUTSITE in php

Tags: php

I need to know, how much arguments a function accepts (including optional args). w/o calling that function and w/o getting errors. Like I can check with `is_callable` before I call a function in order to not get php error.
For example, in javascript every function have a `length` property:

```
Math.sin.length == 1
Array.prototype.slice.length == 2
```

I know, this will return only declared arguments, but there's no support for optional arguments with default values in js syntax.

Is there a similar thing in **php**?
Working in php 5.2+ is enough. Wroking for only global functions (not methods) is also enough.
Hackish solutions like trying to call function with 0 args, then with 1 arg... are highly discouraged, cause function call cost may be very high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php):

```
function a($b, $c = 1) {
    echo $b, $c;
}

$rf = new ReflectionFunction('a');
echo $rf->getNumberOfParameters();
```

In PHP 5.3, `ReflectionFunction` supports closures:

```
$a = function($b, $c = 1) {
    echo $b, $c;
};

$rf = new ReflectionFunction($a);
echo $rf->getNumberOfParameters();
```

Comment: For some reason this results in 0 for `json_decode` at my hoster php5.2.16 all details: http://kirilloid.ru/phpinfo.php while `json_decode` works normally with 2 arguments there. And on php5.3 on my home machine it works ok, resulting in `3`.